# Проигрывание анимации из фонового потока

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, анимация

Приветствую всех! Насколько мне известно, wpf использует два потока:один для пользовательского интерфейса, а другой для обработки событий. И если я правильно понимаю,  вызвать метод BeginAnimation() можно только с использованием  диспетчера, и я пытаюсь поступать так, но ничего не выходит.(кроме надписи о том, что выполняемый поток не может получить доступ к объекту). Возможно , стоит использовать BeginInvoke(), но я не совсем понимаю, для чего нужен второй аргумент. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с моей проблемой!

Comment: WPF использует один поток для своих дел - хоть в обработчиках, хоть где. BeginInvoke вам понадобится только если вы сами своим кодом явно или неявно создали дополнительный поток

Comment: Ух. Учитывая мои способности к написанию хорошего кода, я более чем уверен, что где-то с потоками я точно накосячил, хотя сложно сказать где. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите.

Для отрисовки и своих внутренних дел WPF использует побочные потоки. Но эти потоки для вас невидимы: ваше общение с WPF всё должно происходить в одном-единственном UI-потоке.

Вы можете вызвать метод `BeginAnimation`, если находитесь в UI-потоке; в противном случае вам нужно из фонового потока отправить кусок вашего кода на выполнение в UI-поток.

Этим всем занимается [`Dispatcher`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.7.1). Если у вас есть экземпляр `Dispatcher`'а UI-потока (его можно получить у окна или у объекта `Application.Current` в обычном случае), вы можете узнать, находитесь ли вы в UI-потоке при помощи `dispatcher.CheckAccess()`. Отправить кусок кода (например, вызов `BeginAnimation` или что-то большее) в UI-поток можно, например, при помощи `dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { тут ваш код })`.

(К значению, возвращённому из `dispatcher.InvokeAsync`, можно применить `await`, чтобы дождаться окончания выполнения.)

Comment: Здравствуй! Спасибо за предоставленную информацию!Очень странно, что моя программа себя так ведёт, ибо работаю я всего с одним потоком и дополнительных не использую, или я чего-то не понимаю, пойду искать дополнительную информацию в интернете, дабы не засорять стэк)

Comment: @reinhart: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло!