# Запуск анимации из фонового потока(2)

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, анимация, асинхронность

Благодаря VladD, который ответил мне в прошлый раз здесь -
 [Проигрывание анимации из фонового потока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796649/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) , а также куче различных тем на других форумах, я вроде стал лучше понимать принцип работы с wpf, но с другой стороны еще больше запутался.
  В общем-то, моя цель все еще состоит в том, чтобы запустить анимацию из фонового потока. Теперь я точно установил, что работает код вызова анимации в фоновом потоке, но не могу понять почему. 
  В моей программе есть вызов асинхронного метода, который делает пост-запрос и возвращает ответ:

```
     async Task<string> PostMethod() {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subKey);
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        string json;
        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(Webcam.lastSnapshot)) {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response = await client.PostAsync(uriBase, content);
            json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        return json;
    }
```

И есть функция, в которой вызывается PostMethod и сама анимация, соответственно.

```
      async void Func() {
        string json = await PostMethod();
        ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation();
        //Здесь всякие настройки анимации
        Rect.InvokeAsync(async()=>{ Rect.BeginAnimtion(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, anim);});
    }
```

Если я правильно понимаю, await приостанавливает выполнение метода до тех пор, пока не выполнится асинхронный код после await. Но у меня, почему-то, в окне вывода уведомление о завершении потока приходит позже, чем вызывается метод Rect.InvokeAsync, причем секунд на 5-7. Следовательно, я могу сделать вывод, что  ошибка при проигрывании анимации как-то связана с PostMethod, но я не могу понять как. Прошу помочь разобраться!

Comment: Что такое Rect и откуда у него метод InvokeAsync?

Comment: И как вы вызываете Func()?

Comment: Извиняюсь, упустил обращение к Dispatcher. Rect - прямоугольник(класс Rectangle).Func вызывается посредством "реакции" на событие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте ответ на этот вопрос 
[Async и Await. Контекст синхронизации и выполнения.Конечный автомат. C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750506/async-%D0%B8-await-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-c)

У вас, судя по всему, происходит захват контекста синхронизации не UI потока, что вам не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, сообщение о завершении потока и не должно появляться немедленно.

`Task` выполняется обычно не в новом потоке, а на пуле потоков. Соответственно завершение `Task`'а вовсе не означает завершение потока.

---

Проблему, которую сразу видно — ваша анимация создаётся в фоновом потоке, а это неправильно. Делайте так:

```
dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation();
        //Здесь всякие настройки анимации
        Rect.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, anim);
    });
```

Comment: Какая досадная ошибка) Спасибо, ребята!